# DLL load failed when installing rcnn of MXNet in Windows10

Tags: python-import, mxnet

I have successfully installed MXNet-0.11 in my laptop, whose OS is Windows 10 and GPU is GTX1060. And now I want to install rcnn, I have run the Makefile in the folder example/rcnn in command line using MinGW64. But when I run demo.py, it tells me **DLL load failed**. How do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of commands you are trying to run? And what is exactly the output? Also, may I ask you, is there any specific reason you are trying to install mxnet version 0.11, because the latest version is 1.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last answer of this post https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/installing-mxnet-on-windows/374/8 to see how to install a modern version of mxnet on windows. I have personally not been able to run successfully the makefile of the rcnn example